# I am trying to work with marklogic smart-mastering into my data-hub project keep getting an error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I copied the minimum-example folder content into my environment where I already installed ML9 and the DHF4.  When I try to run the command to install the smart mastering I get an error - command not found.

I am running on an EC2 server and issue the following command as stated in the README:

[ec2-user@server smf-hub]$ gradle mlDeploy

-bash: gradle: command not found

I have the following files which come with it deployed:

gradle (folder),
src (folder),
build.gradle,
gradle.properties,
gradlew,
gradlew.bat,
README.md

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you install Gradle? Or did you try using gradle-wrapper instead, e.g. replace `gradle` with `./gradlew`?

Answer (score 0):

(Building on @grtjn's comment) Running `gradle mlDeploy` is generally done when you have gradle installed globally. It looks like you don't, so the alternative is to use the gradle wrapper that comes with the project.

```
./gradlew mlDeploy
```